# efficient sparse matrix calculation in scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix A (d by d) and I'm trying to subtract multiplication of a dense vector (mean) by itself from it. Right now what I'm doing is to do the subtraction row by row:

```
for i in range(d):
    A[i,:]=A[i,:]-mean[i]*(mean.T)
```

but this is extremely slow as one might anticipate. A is in csr format and I tried converting it to lil to speed up the subtraction but the process is still very slow. I was wondering how can I do this operation faster? one suggestion could be to do the subtraction for a group of rows instead of an individual row. but is there a better way?

Comment: what is `mean` in your example?

Comment: mean is a d by 1 vector so it's multiplication by it's transpose is a d by d matrix. It does not have a relationship with A necessarily.

Comment: If `mean` is an arbitrary vector, then converting to dense and subtracting `mean * mean.T` is the best you can do; the result won't be sparse anyway.

Comment: If you don't get a better answer using sparsity (or after you get one), to answer the question "how can I do this operation faster", take a look at Cython, especially when working with Numpy.

Comment: Using Cython with a scipy sparse matrix is a pain, unless you are familiar with the particular format (e.g. in the case the `csr` indices).